# The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes on sub query

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Im trying to use fulltext search but I got this error:

```
Error Code: 1214. The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes
```

My query is this:

```
 SELECT u.firstName FROM

 ((SELECT firstName as firstName FROM crm_member)

  UNION 

 (SELECT first_name as firstName FROM user)) as u 

  WHERE MATCH(u.firstName) AGAINST("*test*" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Both of the tables `user` and `crm_memeber` already have fulltext indexes.

If I run this queries:

```
SELECT firstName FROM crm_member

WHERE MATCH(firstName) AGAINST("*test*" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Or this:

```
SELECT first_name FROM user

WHERE MATCH(first_name ) AGAINST("*test*" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

I get no errors.

Its seems like here is a problem using match against with result of subquery but I dont understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lose the index because of the `UNION` operation.  Your best bet is to repeat the condition:

```
SELECT u.firstName
FROM ((SELECT firstName as firstName
       FROM crm_member
        WHERE MATCH(firstName) AGAINST("*test*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
      ) UNION 
      (SELECT first_name as firstName
       FROM user
       WHERE MATCH(firstName) AGAINST("*test*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
      )
     ) u;
```

Remember, MySQL materializes subqueries.  In the process it tends to lose information like indexes.

Also, if you know there are no duplicates, then use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: is there a way to keep the index?

Comment: @dasdasd . . . I don't think so, although you could try `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm wrong about the answer, but depends of MySQL version...
Full text is supported by MyIsam table type, they added fulltext indexes on innodb table type in MySQL 5.6